# Change parameter names in redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to do a redirection from old structured links to the new version in htaccess, but I am having no luck.

And the other answers in Stackoverflow dont help.

So I have this link type of link

```
www.example.com/listings/cat/shoes/state/nevada
www.example.com/listings/cat/heels/state/arkansas
www.example.com/listings/cat/skirts/state/florida
```

Which I want to convert to

```
www.example.com/directory/cat/shoes/region/nevada
www.example.com/directory/cat/heels/region/arkansas
www.example.com/directory/cat/skirts/region/florida
```

I have tried this but didn't work as expected.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /listings/cat/(.+)$/state/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/directory/cat/$1/region/$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex has anchor `$` more than once.

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/listings/(cat/.+)/state/(.+)$ /directory/$1/region/$2
```